# What type of wire do you recommend for "breadboard jumpers" where the insulation doesn't melt?

Tags: wire, breadboard, insulation

Every kind of 24AWG solid core wire I've gotten from Amazon over the years has this same problem. If you want to have lovely neat organized breadboards/perf board circuits, you try to bend the wire to the perfect shape like this:
[image]

Then when you go to make the solder connection, the insulation immediately melts off the tight bends:

[image]

I believe most of the these cheaper multicolor wire kits from Amazon are using PVC insulation, while most stranded wire has silicone insulation that doesn't melt. Also, when you purchase those pre-formed "breadboard jumper kits", the insulation on those wires doesn't melt either.

*What should I look for to find **multicolored** 22-24 AWG solid core wire that doesn't have "melty" insulation?* Thanks!

P.S. All I want is to make a circuit look like this!
[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152265/discussion-on-question-by-aj-smoothie-what-wire-do-you-recommend-for-breadboard); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.